# Pine Script "script has too many local scopes, the limit is 500" - What is / counts as a local scope?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Coding my first complex indicator, I finally encountered this error for the first time. My code is indeed big with many if, while and for statements. However, trying to figure out how to fix this issue, I noticed the counter is really... misbehaving, so to speak. For example, I barely made any code changes, yet suddenly it told me I have like 518 out of 500 if statements, while I haven't introduced that many for sure. I merely changed one function where all I did was, like, introduce a ?: conditional into a label.new's title.

However, when I started removing or replacing ifs with switches or ?: conditionals i started noticing it go down seemingly in line with what I was doing (remove 2 ifs - counter goes from 508 to 506).

But then I have counted all uses of if, while and for in my code, and it turned out I have 229, 7 and 16?..... This doesn't amount to 500 at all?....

So I decided to investigate.

This post [Pine script error-add to chart operation failed, reason: script has too many local scopes:521. the limit is 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131163/pine-script-error-add-to-chart-operation-failed-reason-script-has-too-many-loc) talks about adding 500 "if ticker= something do something" statements, abeit in pine v4. And that would produce an error. I've tried replicating it and it doesn't work!

I've tried up to 1000 of statements like

```
if true
    na
```

That didn't trigger any error. I've decided that's too simple and pine somehow inlines that or whatever, so I did complex things like

```
a = true
b = false
if a == b 
    b := not b
    var localvar = 0
    b := b or false
else
    b := true
```

And then copied the if else block 1000 times. No error! Note this is a multi-line function, even declaring a var inside, so it should require a local block by definition?

So... what actually counts as a local scope and what does not? Can anyone please clarify?

EDIT:

**Code #1**
https://pastebin.com/g5qwxp7r

Okay now this code will give 552 local scopes error.

**Code #2**
https://pastebin.com/p7vU2sQ8

Same code but it doesn't give any errors.

**Difference?**

I have removed 5 calls of array.push on line 1421!
Now can someone explain how removing these 5 lines:

```
    array.push(correctionWickRelativeThresholdReachedOr ? succWR : failWR, wickRelative)
    array.push(correctionCloseRelativeThresholdReachedOr ? succCR : failCR, closeRelative)
    array.push(reverseRelativeThresholdReachedOr ? succRR : failRR, reverseRelative)
    array.push(sidewaysThresholdReachedAnd ? succSW : failSW, sideways)
    array.push(atrThresholdReachedAnd ? succWA : failWA, wickAbsolute)
```

Suddenly removed more than 52 local scopes from my code?....

Comment: Scopes are explained in [Language > Script structure > Code](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Script_structure.html?highlight=scope#code). Structures or multi-line function declarations always require a local block. A local block must be indented by a tab or four spaces. Each local block defines a distinct local scope.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen  
Bjorn Mistiaen 
Thank you. In that case, how can you explain that my code can contain 2000 of if/else statements from my example and no error is triggered? while it triggers for my code that contains only 255 if/when/for statements and about 30 functions?

Comment: Not sure why. Maybe adding the offending code to your question could help, so we can take a look.

Comment: well the code is several thousand lines long, but I've added a sample. There's nothing special about it really. Just code...

Comment: Your if/else statements are nested. Each statement that begins with whitespace is a local block (as defined in the manual). That way you easily get to 500.

Comment: But if EACH statement would be, first, why does my example with over 4000 nested statements as defined in the manual produce no error,and second, I have about 2 thousand statements defined like that now with my code, and no error. why is that?

Comment: Please share both codes (working and not working) either through a TradingView (private) publishing or a PasteBin link, and add it to your question. That way we can have a look.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen I have. And I have in process confirmed this is indeed a mess.. Please take a look. One code compiles with 552 local scopes error. Another code, where I remove five calls of array.push, suddenly doesn't error at all! So how come removing 5 calls to built-in function somehow removed over 52 local scopes from my code?...