# How do i create nest list for my symbols in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, nested-lists, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create a list selection for symbols.  The sets are working, but the exchangeList is not.  I want to be able to select the exchange first, and then the sets from that list.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
exchangeList = input.string("COINBASE", title="Exchange", options=["BINANCE", "COINBASE", "KUCOIN"])
setList = input.string("Set 1", title="Coin Sets", options=["Set 1", "Set 2", "Set 3"])

//Coinbase
string s01 = setList == "Set 1" ? f_ticker('COINBASE:00USD'): setList == "Set 2" ? f_ticker('COINBASE:AMPUSD'): f_ticker('COINBASE:ETHBTC')

//BINANCE
string s01 = setList == "Set 1" ? f_ticker('BINANCE:ETHUSDT'): setList == "Set 2" ? f_ticker('BINANCE:LTCUSDT'): f_ticker('BINANCE:ADAUSDT')

//KUCOIN
string s01 = setList == "Set 1" ? f_ticker('KUCOIN:MATICUSDT'): setList == "Set 2" ? f_ticker('KUCOIN:ETCUSDT'): f_ticker('KUCOIN:SOLUSDT')
```

I tried the following code and it didn't work:

```
//KUCOIN
string s01 = exchangeList == "KUCOIN" ? "Coinbase" : setList == "Set 1" ? f_ticker('COINBASE:00USD'): setList == "Set 2" ? f_ticker('COINBASE:AMPUSD'): f_ticker('COINBASE:ETHBTC')
```

I also tried this:

```
if exchangeList == "Coinbase"
    string s01 = setList == "Set 1" ? f_ticker('COINBASE:00USD'): setList == "Set 2" ? f_ticker('COINBASE:AMPUSD'): setList == "Set 3" ? f_ticker('COINBASE:AXLUSD'): f_ticker('COINBASE:UNIBTC')
```

each list starts with string s01 and there are 15 total so I am not sure how to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be perfect but it is working:

```
string s = ""

if exchangeList == "BINANCE"
    if setList == "Set 1"
        s := exchangeList + ":" + "ETHUSDT"
    if setList == "Set 2"
        s := exchangeList + ":" + "LTCUSDT"
    if setList == "Set 3"
        s := exchangeList + ":" + "ADAUSDT"

if exchangeList == "COINBASE"
    if setList == "Set 1"
        s := exchangeList + ":" + "00USD"
    if setList == "Set 2"
        s := exchangeList + ":" + "AMPUSD"
    if setList == "Set 3"
        s := exchangeList + ":" + "ETHBTC"

if exchangeList == "KUCOIN"
    if setList == "Set 1"
        s := exchangeList + ":" + "MATICUSDT"
    if setList == "Set 2"
        s := exchangeList + ":" + "ETCUSDT"
    if setList == "Set 3"
        s := exchangeList + ":" + "SOLUSDT"

f_ticker(s)
```

Comment: This works.,thankyou! Do you know if there is a way around the following error?  Script has too many local scopes: 561. The limit is 500

Comment: That error is showing up because there are too many if statements. There are some solutions for the same issue in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131163/pine-script-error-add-to-chart-operation-failed-reason-script-has-too-many-loc).